# How to check null in Lambda Expression to list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

```
namespace DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework
{
    public class UserDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<User, LogisticContext>, IUserDal
    {
        public List<Role> GetRoles(User user)
        {
            using var context = new LogisticContext();

            return context.UserRoles
                    .Include(x => x.Role)
                    .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)
                    .Select(x => new Role { Id = x.RoleId, Name = x.Role.Name })
                    .ToList();
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to login but already, `role` and `userRole` tables dont' have any data, so it throws a null reference exception.
What can i do to solve this problem?.
[image]

Comment: Kindly remind: Please share your code as a snippet instead of the image. Refer: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I saw you have removed `.DefaultIfEmpty(null)` in the latest version of the question (compare with the previous version), does this still encounter the same error?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible. If both tables have no records then the .Where operates on an empty list to produce an empty list and the .Select takes no action

Comment: @Yong Shun Yes It still  throws same error.

Comment: user parameter is null :) sorry . The problem solved . thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you Define Nullable Property For Role In UserRole
And User Find In UserRole But Role Not Found
You Should Check Role Property Is Not Null

```
return context.UserRoles
  .Include(x => x.Role)
  .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id && x.Role != null)
  .Select(x => new Role { Id = x.RoleId, Name = x.Role.Name })
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the linq query and let the ToList call apart with null checking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework
{
    public class UserDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<User, LogisticContext>, IUserDal
    {
        public List<Role> GetRoles(User user)
        {
            using var context = new LogisticContext();

            return context.UserRoles
                    .Include(x => x.Role)
                    .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)
                    .Select(x => new Role { Id = x.RoleId, Name = x.Role != null ? x.Role.Name : "Not available" })
                    .ToList();
        } 
    }
}
```

Basically what I did here, I applied the ternary conditional operator in case when your Role is different that null we would read data as it is otherwise I would set name to some default value "Not available" but you can set it to whatever you want to.